# Link domain to hosting

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting, cname

I have site at pythonanywhere.com
Now for example I can see it here [100hp100ar.pythonanywhere.com](http://100hp100ar.pythonanywhere.com).

I have bought domain name mydomain.com and want to link it.
I have read this help page about domains without www:

[www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/NakedDomains](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/NakedDomains)
I was told that I should

> Use an A record for yourdomain.com
>
> The A record has to be an IP address -- use the one associated with yourusername.pythonanywhere.com

(This solution suits me more than solution with redirecting cause redirecting costs money)
But how can I know the ip adress associated with  100hp100ar.pythonanywhere.com?
Will

> ping 100hp100ar.pythonanywhere.com

which gives me

> 50.19.109.98
>   Be the stuff I need?

Comment: You need to update your A records `@` and `www` to your destination server - In this case, I would imagine it would be the IP that you gave

Comment: So you mean yes this is what I need?

Comment: Probably. I'm not 100% sure where the IP address goes, but I think it's to your server. You should update these details on your domain, so where you registered the domain and then allow for some time for the nameservers to change over (up to 48 hours).

Comment: Just a note -- redirecting doesn't have to cost money, there's a free service that will do it for you at http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ping`, you can try running `host yourdomain.com`, `dig yourdomain.com` or `nslookup yourdomain.com`.

These will return something like

```
yourdomain.com is an alias for yourusername.pythonanywhere.com
```

If you have everything set up correctly. Also note that it takes time for DNS changes to propagate (so after making the changes at your DNS registrar, don't expect the `host` commands to reflect that change right away even if you have set everything up correctly)